# flutter: same variable returns null in one class, but works fine in another

Tags: flutter, null, return-value, dart-null-safety

I have two different classes, 1)

```
class PostCard extends StatefulWidget {
final Post? post;

const PostCard({Key? key, this.post}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<PostCard> createState() => _PostCardState();
}
```

2nd class:

```
class History extends StatefulWidget {
static const id = '/history';
final Post? post;

const History({Key? key, this.post}) : super(key: key);

@override
_HistoryState createState() => _HistoryState();
}
```

In the first one `widget.post!.weight` returns the value it supposed to return, however in the History class `widget.post!.weight` returns null error on "post!". And I don't understand why? Thanks!
These values are both used wrapped in Text widget:

```
Text((int.parse(widget.post!.weight)* 
 (data.durationSeconds ~/ 
 60)).toStringAsFixed(2).padLeft(2, '0')),
```

error:

```
Null check operator used on a null value

 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
 #0      _HistoryState.build.<anonymous closure> 
 (package:..../..../history.dart:319:56)
 #1      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build 
 (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:457:22)
 #2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build 
 (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1215:28)
 #3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement 
 (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1148:67)
 #4      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:279:35)
 #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild 
 (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1192:24)
 #6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update 
 (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1126:7)
  #7      Element.updateChild 
 (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
```

Comment: can you provide code where you use your `History` class?

Comment: thanks for ur prompt response. I use the value in the formula. I added the Text() widget.

Comment: you provided where `widget.post!.weight` line is called, but I need code where you build your call `History()`

Comment: ooooh, sorry! The PostCard class is used in Stream with firestore, and History is used with Hive. So, I guess, need to look into the build methods. Thanks! I will dig into that now.